# what is wrong with the sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE 1 
(text longtext(4,294,967,295), 
 date VARCHAR(50), 
 time VARCHAR(50), 
 id INT(11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
```

What is wrong with the above SQL statement? I keep getting an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(4,294,967,295), date VARCHAR(50), time VARCHAR(50), id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AU' at line 3

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(4,294,967,295), date VARCHAR(50), time VARCHAR(50), id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AU' at line 3

Comment: What is wrong? Where to start...

Comment: Start reading the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 2):

`1` is a lousy name for a table.  If you use it, you need to escape the name.  Also, commas aren't allow in lengths for character fields and `longtext` doesn't need a length anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE `1` 
(text longtext, 
 date VARCHAR(50), 
 time VARCHAR(50), 
 id INT(11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
)
```

And, you don't "add" a primary key.  You just declare it.